# Is there any way to remove "Screenshot" option from power menu for Android 10+?

Tags: screenshots, power-options

Is there any way to remove "Screenshot" option from power menu for Android 10+ without a 3rd party app, or with a custom xml?

Comment: I don't have "Screenshot" option in long press power button menu on Android 10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] and mention the device model? Manufacturers can customize their ROM, so this feature may not be available on every Android device.

Comment: As far as I know the "Power menu is fixed and can only be changed by an firmware update by the device manufacturer or by installing a different ROM (the latter only if the device is bootloader unlocked).